# Python : Write to textfile using join

Tags: python

I have a function that writes a username followed by a comma and space (', ') and then a password to a text file. The password however needs to be saved without the (', ') comma and space.

```
def add_user_details(user_details: list):
with open ('user.txt', 'a') as file:
    for details in user_details:
        file.write(details)
        file.write(', ')
    file.write('\n')
```

So the ideal outcome should be :

```
username, password
username1, password1
```

Comment: `user_details` is a list as per `user_details: list` while you say it's a dictionary.. what is format of data stored in `user_details` I mean how is it stored ?

Comment: You write `user_details` is a dictionary, but your function parameter is defined as a list.

Comment: Yes, apologies I removed that part.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
for details in user_details:
    file.write(details)
    file.write(', ')
```

With

```
file.write(", ".join(user_details))
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I think I was just stuck adding for loops everwhere.